# How to make = work like + in breqn?

Tags: breqn

I want to write chains of equations like `ugly formula = expanded = moving things around = simplified = nice formula` and to have linebreaks in space-efficient places regardless of margin size and the number of columns. I feel like the formulas shouldn't be broken up so that the reader can parse them without moving their eyes all the time. I was looking around and stumbled upon breqn, which seems to be powerful enough but somehow not willing to fulfill my wishes. It linebreaks on any `=`, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath*}
a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

will make a tower of `=a`s. The `=`s can be substituted with `\hiderel{=}`s but then it never linebreaks. I thought for a moment that breqn is just a scam and only changes the default between "linebreak" and "no linebreak", but then I discovered that something like `\begin{dmath*} a+a+...\end{dmath*}` actually produces what I'd want - it tries to fit as many `a`s in a row as possible, but if there's too much of them moves them to the next line. Could it do the same for me but with `=`s?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat is this ok? What do you mean by "what you have tried", I've only really tried googling, I have no idea how to do anything with the deep arcane tex stuff.

Comment: I must confess to possessing no enthusiasm for helping *anybody* typeset `a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a` -- with "linebreaks in space-efficient places" or in any other manner. Might you be willing to provide a slightly more realistic use case? Oh, and why did you think, even for a moment, that "that `breqn` is just a scam"?

Comment: @Mico I could, but I don't see how that would help - I don't want to just typeset a specific math expression, I want to find a general, automatic solution for the problem described at the beginning of my post. The `a=a=...` was just an example to illustrate how breqn works. I thought it actually can't automatically break lines, but it can, I just don't know how to make it do that at `=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use inline formulas, that *are* broken into lines:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,varwidth}

\newenvironment{breakmath}[1][0.8]
 {\begin{equation*}\begin{varwidth}{#1\columnwidth}\raggedright$\displaystyle}
 {$\end{varwidth}\end{equation*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{breakmath}
a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a
\end{breakmath}

\end{document}
```

The optional parameter specifies the maximum width allowed, default 80% of the column width. So, if you call `\begin{breakmath}[0.7]` you get maximum width 70%.

[image]

If you prefer equals signs at the beginning of the line, you can do as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,varwidth}

\newenvironment{breakmath}[1][0.8\columnwidth]
 {\begin{equation*}\begin{varwidth}{#1}\raggedright\makebreakequals$\displaystyle}
 {$\end{varwidth}\end{equation*}}

\newcommand{\breakequals}{%
  \penalty\relpenalty\stdequals\nobreak
}
\newcommand{\makebreakequals}{%
  \edef\stdequals{\mathchar\the\mathcode`=\relax}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`=\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\breakequals
  \mathcode`=="8000
}

\begin{document}

\begin{breakmath}
a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a=a
\end{breakmath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Such a nice suggest...XMAS wishes

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that when the formulas are high (like with fractions and power towers), the vertical space between them is very thin. Is there a way to increase it?

Comment: @acupoftea You can add `\linespread{1.2}` or something like that before `\raggedright`

Comment: @egreg Thanks, the "something like that" that seems to work is `\lineskip=9\lineskip`

Comment: @egreg yet another wish, is it possible to encourage it to place the `=` signs at the beginnings of lines instead of at the ends? I tried `=~` and `=\linebreak` instead of `=` and also `\mbox{$=a$}` but then it doesn't break at all.

Comment: @acupoftea Added.